# Searching data from JSON using JQuery UI autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

How can I use JQuery UI autocomplete using fetched json data? It's not working on mine.

I use this example http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/, but instead of hard-coded data I fetch from json.

My json data is from a url `localhost/myproject/output/names`.

html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search" id="search">
```

js

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
      source: "localhost/myproject/output/names"
    });
  });
  </script>
```

json data

```
[{"fullname":"John Smith"},{"fullname":"Juan dela Cruz"}]
```

**EDIT**

I already manage to fix the issue with json data as commented by @artm. now it's `[{John Smith},{Juan dela Cruz}]`

But another problem is, when I type the letter `o` both of the two is suggested even though only `John Smith` contains `o`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Response is supposed to be `["John Smith", "Juan dela Cruz"]`

Comment: how can I do that in PHP? Because I just use `json_encode` in the output of my query for fullnames.

Comment: I don't know php, search on here.

Comment: You're not processing json response?

Comment: Are you getting json response from server or you've trouble implementing it?

Comment: I'm getting json responce from the server but front-end cannot use it in autocomplete since it has a key `fullname`

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI autocomplete expects either an array of strings, for example

```
["John Smith", "Juan dela Cruz"]
```

Or an array of objects having `label` and `value`properties, for example:

```
[ { label: "name", value: "John Smith" }, { label: "name", value: "Juan dela Cruz" }... ]
```

In case if your data source is not directly sending data in this format, you can pass a function to the [`source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option, in which you can retrieve data from the data source and modify it accordingly.

The function receives two arguments:

- A request object with single `term`property whoes value is the user input
- A callback function to which you should pass the data in correct format.

Try something along

```
$(function() {
  $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response){
     $.ajax("localhost/myproject/output/names",{ // retrieve the data
          //ajax settings
         success: function(data){
            var matches = $.map(data,function(item){ // create an array of strings

               // find the matching items manually in insert to the array
               if(item.fullname.indexOf(request.term)>=0)
                 return item.fullname;
            });
            response(matches); // pass the results to response callback
         }
     });
   }
  });
});
```

---

Side note: The code is not tested and it is just for giving a broad overview.

Comment: I got an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search`

Comment: @Port8080 Here's a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/h8v0zo7a/) for the json structure you mentioned...