# autocomplete functionality on dynamic textbox

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-ui, model-view-controller, jquery-autocomplete

I have a scenario as follows,

Need to put autocomplete functionality on dynamic textbox with onkeyup functionality

My code is as follows, Here i have invoked a function "GetName" on buttonclick where am loadin the dynamic textboxes

```
function GetName() {
  var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ prefixText: $('#search').val(), Id: $("#SearchType").val()
});

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { jsonData: dataToSend },
        url: "GetName",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#ResourceNames").empty();
            $("#ResourceNames").append('<table>');

            $.each(result, function (i, Name) {                
                $("#ResourceNames").append('<tr><td ><Label>' + Name.Value + '</label></td><td>  <input type="text" id="Supervisor" class = "form-control", onkeyup="GetResource(\'' + Name.Text + '\');"/></td></tr>');                  

            });

        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
        }
    })
    $("#ResourceNames").append('</table>');
}
```

Here onkeyup event of textbox supervisor am calling the below function getresource with an argument

```
function GetResource(i) {

    debugger;
    var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ prefixText: $("#Supervisor").val(), designation: i });
    $.ajax({
        url: "GetSupervisor",
        data: { jsonData: dataToSend },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#Supervisor").autocomplete({source:data});
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('error; ' + error.text);
        }

    });

}
```

am not able to bind autocomplete data to dynamic textbox, can anyone help me out on the same?

Comment: What is the structure of `data` in the success callback..?

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code:

- First of all jQuery doesn't concatenates strings into `DOM`, it creates a `DOMElement`. So,
   `$("#ResourceNames").append('<table>');` will append an entire `<table>` element. Anything you append to `#ResourceNames` will be added after the table, not inside it.
- The HTML you're appending contains `id`. So there can be multiple elements with same `id` which is invalid, depending on the response. It's better to use a common classname for those elements instead.
- You don't need to manually handle the `keyup` event. You can specify the `url` you want to hit as the value of the [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option of autocomplete, provided it returns a response suitable for the autocomplete. see this [example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) in docs.
- Instead of passing the value via the inline handler, you can store the value as a `data-*` attribute and access it later.

So your code should be something along:

```
function GetName() {

  var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ prefixText: $('#search').val(), Id: $("#SearchType").val()});

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { jsonData: dataToSend },
    url: "GetName",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        var htmlString ="<table>";

        $.each(result, function (i, Name) {                
            htmlString +="<tr><td ><Label>" + Name.Value + "</label></td><td> <input type='text'  class = 'form-control Supervisor' data-name='"+ Name.Text + "'/></td></tr>";                  
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status);
    }
 })
 $("#ResourceNames").append(htmlString);
 $(".Supervisor")..autocomplete({
     source: "GetSupervisor" // where GetSupervisor is your data source
 });
}
```

If you want to manually send requests along with data and pass the results into the autocomplete, you can specify an function as the value of source option. (See [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26523685/2333214) for more info). for example:

```
$(".Supervisor").autocomplete({
     source: function(request,response){
       /*send the request here. 
       request.term contains the current value entered in textfield
       pass the results you want to display like response(data)*/
     }
 });
```

Read the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), play with it for a while and you'll be able to get it working.

Comment: Hi T J Thanks for your answer, how do i get the data-name of textbox in my autocomplete event